# Datatable.Compute returns what?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a simple Cart DataTable.

```
static DataTable dtItem = new DataTable();

dtCart.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(string));
dtCart.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dtCart.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(double));
dtCart.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(double));
dtCart.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(double), "Price*Amount");
```

And i want to check if there is no item in the cart by counting the amount.

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(dtCart.Compute("SUM(Amount)", "")) == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("No item in the cart!");
    return;
}
```

But if there is no rows in the cart, the Compute() returns a null value that cannot be converted.

Then i added :

```
if (dtCart.Compute("sum(Amount)", "") == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("No item in the cart!");
    return;
}
```

And somehow it passed the if, no MessageBox Shown.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are working with a Datatable and not a List of your own class?

Comment: You have specified the `Amount` column as type `double` yet you are using `Convret.ToInt32` when summing that column. If you can only select whole number amounts then that column should be type `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using ADO.NET, database nulls are represented by `DBNull.Value`, so that is what `Compute` will return in that case:

```cs
var totalAmount = dtCart.Compute("SUM(Amount)", string.Empty);

if (totalResult == DBNull.Value || Convert.ToDouble(totalAmount) == 0.0)
{
    // ...
}
```

Of course, given that you have no choice but to test two conditions, you could just test whether there are any rows first:

```cs
if (dtCart.Rows.Count == 0 ||
    Convert.ToDouble(dtCart.Compute("SUM(Amount)", string.Empty)) == 0.0)
{
    // ...
}
```